# How can I stop h2 being in blocking my hibernate querys so much

Tags: hibernate, h2

I've been using h2 (1.3.172) for my application via hibernate for a while, and after solving some non-h2 performance issues my performance bottleneck is h2. My database is quite simple, there are 10 tables and the volumes are less than 100,000 records per table as well so well within h2 capabilities, but I think the problem is with multi-threading.

I'm essentially using hibernate/h2 to keep memory consumption under control in my application. My application works on files using a  pipeline approach, there is no limit on how many files can be processed so if I stored the data in memory I would quickly hit OutOfMemory. Each file typically go through ten stages of processing, each stage has its own executor service, as file moves from one stage to another it is added as a job on the relevent executor service. Very little data is stored in memory, instead as the job is started on the executor data about the file is retrieved from the database, and as the job completes data is written back to the database. We have ten executors each with thread pool of size of machine cores, so on a 4 machine core we could in theory have 40 requests to database at any time, but more typically we have less then 10. So we have a number of transactions going on concurrently mostly involving a small amount of rows.

My application is multi-threaded and if I run a profiler against it I find most of the time my threads are in a blocked state waiting on executeQuery() or executeUpdate(). I read that h2 is single threaded so I assume the problem is caused by h2 synchronizing requests, rather than locking but I may have misunderstood this. I already have set MVCC=TRUE so that h2 does row instead of table locking, but I still get ocassional timeouts - is there something I can set to check the locks being used.

I read there was a MULTI_THREADING option but that cannot be used with MVCC, this is a shame because I feel I need both option if I remove MVCC=TRUE that would mean h2 will lock the table every time I do an insert or update, and because I only have a few tables they would almost always be locked.

So, I feel that the blocking could be massively reduced but Im unclear what the underlying problem is and how to proceed

**Tests**
This is my starting point, test case takes 3mins 14 seconds

```
3:14,FILE_LOCK=SOCKET;MVCC=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

I tried various combinations such as

```
3:02,FILE_LOCK=SOCKET;MVCC=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOG=0;CACHE_SIZE=65536;LOCK_MODE=0;
2:56,FILE_LOCK=SOCKET;MVCC=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOG=0;;CACHE_TYPE=SOFT_LRU;LOCK_MODE=0;
1:05,FILE_LOCK=SOCKET;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000
```

and I found the only thing that made a massive difference was removing the MVCC=TRUE option, but unfortunately my number of lock timeouts increased from almost zero to loads so unfortunately some of the required processing didn't occur, which may be the reason the total time was quicker
 because some of the stages within the application wasn't done, or does use of MVCC slow things down.

I tried using MULTI_THREADED=TRUE but it didnt seem to work for me at all

**About use in MultiCore systems**

I just read this explanation of the MULTI_THREADED option https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/VoE3AU7mSuM

Thomas says

> The default is "not multi-threaded" meaning only one statement can run
>   at any time (per database). There is a synchronized block around
>   running a statement. When multi-threaded is enabled, then the
>   synchronized statement is on the session (connection) instead of on
>   the database object.
>
> The option is to increase concurrency, not throughput. The default
>   setting is usually not a problem except if you have long running
>   queries.

If Ive understood it right it means that when disabled although h2 can accept multiple connections it will only be processing one query at a time, but even when it is enabled then it swap between querys half way through but will still actually be only processing one query at a time, i.e it can start processing query1, then swap to query2, then back to query 1 ectera but will never actually using cpu to process query1 and query 2 in parallel.

So in either case although switching between cpus it will only ever be using one cpu at any time. So if you have a powerful machine with for example 16 cores, and the bottleneck is the database , adding more cores will not help at all **because h2 only ever using one core a time** ?

This seems a real restriction, and I wonder how it compares with Derby or any other embedded java database.

Answer (score 1):

There are threads that are blocked, that might be, yes, but I would *first* concentrate on those threads that are *not* blocked, that means that are consuming the CPU time or disk I/O. What statements are those? Are they queries that don't use an index? Do you have indexes? Or do you unnecessarily insert / remove rows? See also the documentation on [how to analyze performance problems](http://h2database.com/html/performance.html#application_profiling).

Comment: I do have indexes, and the problem occurs even if I start with an empty database (whereby row scans probably quicker than using indexes anyway), I think my statements are sensible although because I use Hibernate its not so easy to see what is going on. I will investigate the sql as suggested but I would appreciate your input on the Multicore section of the question.

Comment: please review my multi-core summary in the question

Answer (score 0):

While I love H2, I think it's not the best option in your case. You should try to Derby which is a much more mature and production ready ([it's a descendant of the IBM product Cloudspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Derby)).

The next step then is to lessen transaction isolation. If you see [this document](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop74.html) for types of locks used by each isolation level.

Since you use Hibernate, switching the database shouldn't take too long (just change the JDBC config and load the existing data into a new database).

Just like H2, you can embed Derby.

Comment: I do actually use Derby for another application, my view was h2 had overtaken derby i terms of features and performance but that was mostly based on h2s own benchmark which I now see are single connection benchmarks

Comment: H2 is much faster at startup and processing data in a single threaded environment. As soon as threads enter the picture, H2 is much more conservative and less optimized. Overall, Derby is slower but more reliable. That's why I use H2 for tests and Derby for real production (this also helps to iron DB-specific code out of the code).

Comment: so according to the docs it can do row level locking similar to h2's MVCC mode - I assume it does this itself intelligently ? , I hope so because trying to use h2 without this mode meant I kept getting far too may lock timeout due to table locks.

Comment: Why do you ask? Performance isn't something that can be deducted. You will have to try whether it really works in your case.

Comment: I asked because using table level locking instead of row level locking in h2 really sucked, and I dont particulary want to devote much effort to using derby if it doesnt have this feature.

Comment: If you still want to do it with deduction, then read the document that I linked. It explains which locks Derby supports and when it will use which one.

Comment: @Aaraon Digula i did read it and saw it had row level locking but it wasn't clear to be when it would be used, I was hoping someone with experience of using derby would just know the answer.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: I've been working with half a dozen different databases and even the people who wrote those can't answer that ;-) The query optimizer will determine at runtime which kind of lock to use. That depends on: The query, the actual indexes on the table, the indexes that the optimizer deems worthy to use, the data in the table, the number of rows, sometimes the number of columns, the types of the columns and any other factor that some genius found useful. The net result is that no one can tell how fast a query will be without actually executing it.

Comment: And executing it on the actual data, of course. So even an integration test can't protect you against surprises there.

Comment: I just wanted confirmation that it could do row level locking